webots mass question
I've set the robot's mass to 100,000 in Webots, but the robot's wheels are sinking into the ground. Adjusting the CFM to 1e-05 didn't improve the situation. How can I solve this? Can Webots only simulate lightweight robots?
Please translate the above question into English, ensuring the content is accurate and the language is polite.

the question is in English... why do you ask for a translation?

you set the mass to 100,000 what? ... kilograms? ... tons?

Check this page: https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/modeling?version=R2021b#my-robot-is-heavy-and-sinks-into-the-ground-constantly
